# Moving AX into CL - Invalid combination of opcode and operands

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, bootloader

I am trying to move a value stored in my AX register to my CL register. I am also trying to do this with register pairs (move from to move into) BX : DH, and CX : CH.

Here is my code.

```
;;;
;;; Stage 1 - Boot Loader
;;; 

BITS 16             ; Start in 16 bit real mode
ORG 0x7C00          ; Loaded by BIOS at 0x7C00

start:  jmp stage1      ; Jump to the stage 1 section

;;;
;;; Parameter Block
;;; 

SECTORS_TRACK   dw  18  ; Sectors per track
HEADS_CYLINDER  dw  2   ; Heads per cylinder

;;;
;;; Strings Block
;;;

stage1_message  db  'Stage 1 - 16 bit real mode', 13, 10, 0

;;;
;;; Print String Function
;;; Input:
;;; - si = Null terminated string
;;; Output:
;;; - None
;;; 

print:
    lodsb           ; Load next byte from string in SI to AL
    or al, al       ; Does AL equal 0?
    jz print_done       ; Yes, null terminator found, return
    mov ah, 0eh     ; No, print the character
    int 10h
    jmp print       ; Repeat until null terminator found
print_done:
    ret         ; We are done, return

;;;
;;; LBA to CHS Function
;;; - Sector 1 = LBA 0
;;; Input:
;;; - ax = LBA value
;;; Output:
;;; - ax = Sector
;;; - bx = Head
;;; - cx = Cylinder
;;; Credit:
;;; - http://www.osdever.net/tutorials/view/lba-to-chs
;;;

lbachs:
    push dx
    xor dx, dx
    mov bx, [SECTORS_TRACK]
    div bx
    inc dx
    push dx
    xor dx, dx
    mov bx, [HEADS_CYLINDER]
    div bx
    mov cx, ax
    mov bx, dx
    pop ax
    pop dx
    ret

;;;
;;; Load Stage 2 Function
;;;

stage2:
    mov ax, 0x01        ; LBA 1 = Sector 2
    call lbachs     ; Convert LBA to CHS

    mov ah, 0x02        ; Read disk sectors function
    mov al, 0x01        ; Read one sector only (512 bytes)
    mov dl, 0x00        ; Drive 0 (Floppy Disk 1)

    mov cl, ax      ; Sector - Stored in AX - ERROR
    mov dh, bx      ; Head - Stored in BX - ERROR
    mov ch, cx      ; Cylinder - Stored in CX - ERROR

    mov bx, 0x2000      ; Put loaded data into segment 0x2000:0x0000
    mov es, bx      ; Load segment into ES (Segment parameter)
    mov bx, 0x0000      ; Load segment offset into BX (Offset parameter)

    int 0x13        ; Call BIOS read disk sectors function
    jc stage2       ; Error occurred, try loading again

    jmp 0x2000:0x0000   ; Loading complete, jump to stage 2

;;;
;;; Stage 1 Section
;;;

stage1:
    mov si, stage1_message  ; Load the stage 1 message
    call print      ; Call the print function

    jmp stage2      ; Attempt to load stage 2

;;;
;;; Footer Information
;;;

times 510-($-$$) db 0       ; Fill remainder of bootloader with 0's
dw 0xAA55           ; Standard PC boot signature at the end
```

The three lines that are causing problems are near the bottom above `stage1:` and are marked with the words `ERROR`

If anyone can help me with this I would greatly appreciate it. Also, if you notice anything else out of the ordinary in my code, feel free to let me know. I am developing this as a first stage bootloader that moves into a secondary kernel.

Thank you in advance for your advice and consideration.

Comment: The mov instruction requires both operands to be of the same bit length. Therefore you cannot mov ax (a 16 bit register) into cl because cl has 8 bits. Valid alternatives: mov cl, al or mov cl, ah.

Comment: Silly mistake, we've all made it, so this is a good question, but I wanted you to know that I just voted for your question +1, not because it's a silly mistake that I've made 47 times before, but because you have commented your code well; each instruction, plus headers for various sections.  This is the kind of code that gets attention; and gets answered.

Comment: @User.1 Thank you so much for your kind words, I'm glad that my questions are pleasing to other users such as yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem, as the comment to your original question states, is that you're trying to move the contents of a 16 bit register into an 8 bit register. You can't do that because the registers are different sizes.

If you want to move data from the AX register into the CL register, you have to decide if you want the low bits (the AL register) or the high bits (the AH register). That is, you can write:

```
mov cl,al   ; moves the low 8 bits of AX into CL
```

Or

```
mov cl,ah   ; moves the high 8 bits of AX into CL
```

But you can't put all 16 bits of AX into the 8 bits of CL.

Now, considering your code. You have:

```
call lbachs     ; Convert LBA to CHS

mov ah, 0x02        ; Read disk sectors function
mov al, 0x01        ; Read one sector only (512 bytes)
mov dl, 0x00        ; Drive 0 (Floppy Disk 1)

mov cl, ax      ; Sector - Stored in AX - ERROR
mov dh, bx      ; Head - Stored in BX - ERROR
mov ch, cx      ; Cylinder - Stored in CX - ERROR
```

That's not going to work well because you're calling `lbachs` to get some information in the AX, BX, and CX registers, but then you immediately stomp on AH and AL (the two halves of AX). You need to change your order of operations so that you don't overwrite stuff. I think what you want is something like:

```
call lbachs

mov ch, cl      ; Cylinder (returned in CX by lbachs)
mov cl, al      ; sector number (returned in AX by lbachs)
mov dh, bl      ; head (returned in BX by lbachs)
mov ah, 02      ; Read disk sectors function
mov al, 0x01    ; one sector
mov dl, 0x00    ; Drive 0
```

Note that here I use the values returned by `lbachs` and *then* overwrite the registers in which those values were returned.